# GROUP BY / Aggreggate function clarification

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I have an SQL Query for each of my 2 `Gridview` elements. One is getting all the transactions by branch and transaction date:

```
SELECT 
            tb_TransactionDetails.TxnID,
            tb_TransactionDetails.BranchCode, 
            tb_TransactionDetails.TxnDate, 
            tb_TransactionDetails.ReferenceNo,
            tb_TransactionType.TxnTypeName,
            tb_CurrencyCode.CCYDesc,
            tb_TransactionDetails.CCYAmount,
            tb_RecordStatus.StatusDesc,
            (tb_TransactionName.FirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.MiddleName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.LastName,'')) as 'Client',
            (tb_TransactionName.AddressLine1  + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine2, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(tb_TransactionName.AddressLine3, '')) as 'Address',
            tb_TransactionName.WhoAdded,
            tb_TransactionName.DateAdded,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (ORDER BY BranchCode ) AS RowNumber
            FROM (((tb_TransactionType inner join tb_TransactionDetails 
                on tb_TransactionType.TxnTypeCode = tb_TransactionDetails.TxnType)
                INNER JOIN tb_CurrencyCode on tb_TransactionDetails.CCYCode = tb_CurrencyCode.CCYCode)
                inner join tb_RecordStatus on tb_TransactionDetails.RecordStatus = tb_RecordStatus.StatusCode)
                LEFT JOIN tb_TransactionName
            on tb_TransactionDetails.TxnID = tb_TransactionName.TxnID
            WHERE BranchCode = '1003' 
            and TxnDate = '12/13/2013'
```

and one is getting all the users in the system:

```
    select
    USR.UserName,
    USR.BranchID,
    (ISNULL(USR.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL((SUBSTRING(USR.MiddleName,1,1) + '.' ),'') + ' ' + ISNULL(USR.LastName,'')) as 'Name',
    MBS.IsLockedOut,
    USR.LastActivityDate,
    MAX(STUFF(fxMerge.RoleId, 1, 2, '')) as 'Roles'
    from (aspnet_Membership as MBS inner join aspnet_Users as USR
    on USR.ApplicationId = USR.ApplicationId and MBS.UserId = USR.UserId)
    inner join aspnet_UsersInRoles UIR
    on USR.UserId = UIR.UserId

    CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT ', ' + RoleName 
    FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles UIR1
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles RM ON UIR1.RoleId = RM.RoleID
    WHERE UIR.UserId = UIR1.UserId
    FOR XML PATH('')) fxMerge (RoleId)

where USR.UserName = 'JSmith'

group by USR.UserName, USR.BranchID, USR.FirstName, USR.MiddleName, USR.LastName, MBS.IsLockedOut, USR.LastActivityDate
```

one thing I'm confused about, is that the 1st query does not need a `GROUP BY` clause, while the 2nd one does. My question is, why? I've been running the 1st query hundreds of times no problem in my system, without ever having the need of a `GROUP BY` clause, and the Gridview displays the expected results. While on my 2nd query, It's only when I add the long `GROUP BY` clause that the query executes successfully on the SQL Server Management studio, then nothing shows up on my `Gridview`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your second query has a MAX(). If you want the highest or lowest value, or the count or any other aggregate function, you'll need to specify how to group it.